# ¿Para qué es el parámetro extra en bselect? (plugin de jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando un plugin de *jQuery* llamado [*bselect*](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/select-box-bselect.html). En la función del controlador de eventos veo que está confirmada de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#custom-select').on('selected.bselect',function(e,params){
// after an item selected
});
```

Sé que el parámetro `e` es justamente para el *event handler*, pero no sé qué contiene ni para qué sirve el parámetro `params`.

Estoy tratando de aprender jQuery, ¿podrían decirme dónde puedo encontrar documentación sobre esta duda?

Comment: Listo, lo he puesto en español ahora, gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). He redactado una respuesta, espero que solucione las dudas que tengas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según puedes ver en el [código fuente en github](https://github.com/losmicar/bselect/blob/master/jquery.bselect.js#L286):

```
this.element.trigger("select.bselect", {bselect : this.id, element : elem, obj : this});
```

Se está usando una característica de los eventos que [permite enviar parámetros adicionales a un controlador de evento de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-event-extraParameters):

```
.trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )
```

Lo que significa que cuando se genere el evento `params` contendrá tres propiedades:

- `bselect`: el `id` del elemento del DOM.
- `element`: el contenido de `elem` ([parámetro de la función](https://github.com/losmicar/bselect/blob/master/jquery.bselect.js#L279)).
- `obj`: el propio elemento (`this`).

Sabiendo que `this` está en `params.obj`, podremos acceder al contenido de la propiedad [`settings`](https://github.com/losmicar/bselect/blob/master/jquery.bselect.js#L20) con:

```
$('#custom-select').on(
  'select.bselect',
  (e, params) => {
    /* Mostrar el contenido de "this.settings" */
    console.log('Ver aquí:', params.obj.settings);
  }
);
```

Ejemplo en funcionamiento:

```js
let data = {1 : "Angular", 2 : "jQueryScript", 3 : "React", 4 : "Vue.js"};
$('#custom-select').bselect({
  data : data,
  search : true,
  selected : 2,
  width : '200px',
  defaultText : "Select...",
});
$('#custom-select').on(
  'select.bselect',
  (e, params) => {
    /* Mostrar el contenido de "this.settings" */
    miConsoleLog('Ver aquí:', params.obj.settings);
  }
);
```

```html
<script>let miConsoleLog = console.log; console.log = function() {};</script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/select-box-bselect/bselect.css" /><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script><script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/select-box-bselect/jquery.bselect.js"></script>
<div id="custom-select"></div>
```

Nota: este complemento de jQuery parece estar en desarrollo y contiene envíos de datos de depuración a la consola de javascript. No te recomiendo su uso en producción.

Comment: OscarGarcia. Super completa tu respuesta. Vi el codigo fuente y el link de la documentacion de jquery y todo se aclaro para ese parametro. Solo quiero hacerte una pregunta al respecto y que es muy tonta, perdon: en este contexto a que hace referencia "this" (obj: el propio elemento (this).) ? Hace referencia al objeto del dom o al evento? Donde puedo encontrar documentacion para aclarar esa duda? Recien estoy aprendiendo como utilizar estos handlers y no puedo disipar esa duda

Comment: Ha sido un placer ser de ayuda, David. En cuanto a [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this), hace referencia al ámbito en el que nos encontramos en ese momento, pero depende de la forma en la que se llame a la función. En el enlace que te proporciono se explica con detalle y con muchos ejemplos. Creo que hay por aquí alguna pregunta sobre ese mismo tema respondida. Si quieres más información es mejor redactar una nueva pregunta, así podría ser de ayuda a otras personas con las mismas dudas.

Comment: En cuanto a esta respuesta, si solucionó tu duda, agradecería que la marcaras como correcta (la marca **✔** a su izquierda) para darla por solucionada.

Comment: Entendido Oscar. Ya esta hecho. Formulare otra pregunta respecto a this cuando tenga mas info. Gracias por tu ayuda!